# VFD and motor compatibility

Tags: motor, power-electronics, induction-motor, vfd, motor-design

I am looking for a VFD. The motor has following specifications:[Motor nameplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8zvs.jpg)

YE2-1329-4 and JB/T11707-2013

5.5 kW, 400V, Δ, 11.3 A ,
50Hz,   CosΘ 0.82,  IP 55,  1460 rpm,   87.7.

Is above motor compatible with VFD? Motor will be used with a conveyor belt at variable speed.

Thanks

Comment: There probably is no doubt that this is a 3-phase induction motor, but that is essential. It would be better if the motor nameplate stated that it is compatible with VFD operation. Without specific guidance from the motor manufacturer, I would not operate continuously at full load below about 2/3 of rated speed. All questions about using purchased products should be directed to the product manufacturer or seller. Those are usually not questions about electrical engineering theory or design, the kind of questions for which this site is intended. Voting to close the question.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Is every 3 phase asynchronous motor compatible with VFD? It was a chinese product and the manufacturer does not exist any more. Sorry for inconvience.

Comment: Every 3-phase asynchronous motor is generally compatible with VFD. Each one may have a different range of speed for continuous operation at rated torque without overheating. For some, VFD switching transient voltage suppression may be required. VFD manuals should provide guidance. Do not buy a VFD without first downloading and reading the manual. If you can not get the manual in advance, don't buy the product.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the matter of the suitability of the motor winding insulation to withstand the stresses caused by how VFDs operate. As a general rule, newer motors are being made with winding insulation that is designed for higher voltages so that they can better handle being operated from a VFD. But your motor nameplate looks old, so it likely was not made with these newer materials. The result will be a foreshortened useful life of the motor, maybe as short as a few weeks. You can purchase what's called a "sine wave filter" to go between the VFD and the motor, but that filter will likely cost you as much or more than the cost of a newer more suitable motor.